# Is it Acceptable to Ask questions Based Upon and Entire solution Uploaded to SkyDrive?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

All, I am new to WPF and I have a basic application that I am using to learn MVVM etc. Now, I have an issue with data binding to a `DataGrid` but due to the verbosity of the MVVM pattern to get the required help would involve a large question to provide the facts. in this case, is it acceptable to provide a link to the full project on the SkyDrive for people to look at?

Answer (score 9):

No. You need to include the code that you want reviewed into the question.

If you have too much code, you could try to simplify your code or post only the relevant parts.